# Advance jQuery Animation Queue with Keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, queue

In jQuery code, I am attempting to move from .animate call to subsequent .animate calls with a key press, ideally with the ability to move forward and backwards in the queue. I have my animation built as a series of callbacks for serial execution now. For example:

```
<script>
$(document).keydown(function () {
    $("#rect").animate({
        width: "100px",
        height: "100px",
    }, 2000).animate({
        width: "200px",
        height: "200px",
        marginLeft: "500px",
        marginTop: "300px",
    }, 5000);
});
</script>
```

Is it possible to use .queue such that the second animation would not trigger until a second keypress?

Thank you for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .queue the second animation and then use .dequeue to execute it like this:

```
$('#rect').click(function(){
$("#rect").animate(
{
    width: "100px",
    height: "100px"
} ,2000)
.queue(function(){
    $(this).animate(
        {
            width: "200px",
            height: "200px",
            marginLeft: "500px",
            marginTop: "300px",
        },5000);

    $(this).click(function(){
        $.dequeue(this);
    });

});
```